# Unable to connect to azure kubernetes cluster with kubectl

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I am following the instructions on Microsoft's webpage:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough

I have created a cluster on Azure using "az aks create ...".  I am able to fetch the credentials via "az aks get-credentials...".

But, when I use "kubectl get nodes", it says: "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: Could you please run this command to test it ` curl --insecure https://***.***.azmk8s.io/ ` with your FQDN of cluster?

Comment: Hi, you need to verify whether k8s client(kubectl) is connecting to right k8s api server. use following command to view the result `kubectl config view`

Comment: curl --insecure... responded with "unauthorized".  kubectl config view didn't work on powershell but I created a linux VM on azure and kubectl get nodes is now working as does kubectl config view.  But, it's still not working on powershell from my laptop.

Comment: What exactly does "kubectl config view didn't work on powershell" mean? What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. On PowerShell, it returns no clusters like so: `apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ""
    user: ""
  name: myCluster
current-context: myCluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: clusterUser_myResourceGroup_myCluster
  user: {}
- name: myClusterCluster
  user: {}`  But when I try it from my Linux VM running on the azure cloud, it returns the FQDN for my cluster and the redacted certificate etc.

Comment: I believe the problem can be in different versions of kubectl on your machine and on Azure. At least for me, it helped.